# Implementation of NSOperationQueue by sending request & Storing response in Database parallely

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsoperationqueue

I have implemented NSOPERATIONQUEUE By sending request and i can able to download response from server but the problem is i cant able to parallely process the sqlite to insert/update the response,i am getting Database Locked Error.So Can anyone suggest me a solution to work with database for insertion/updation of my downloaded response??

I have created a NSOperation Class as PageLoadOperation and i will pass request 7 times to that NSOperation class and add it to queue as below

```
PageLoadOperation *pageLoad=[[PageLoadOperation alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest];
[queue addOperation:pageLoad];
```

In Main i can able to send request by below NSURLConnection

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                               queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
 [self openConnection];
 [self doSomethingWithData:data];
 [self closeConnection];
}];
```

and in doSomethingWithData method i will insert/update the response by converting data to NSString                                                                                                 I have separately created method for opening the database connection and once insertion/updation completed i will closeconnection by following methods

```
-(BOOL)openConnection
{
   database=nil;

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   if(sqlite3_open([[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataStore"] UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
   {
       NSLog(@"DB Connection Established successfully");
       return YES;
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"DB not connected");
       return NO;
   }   
 }

 -(BOOL)closeConnection
 { 
     NSLog(@"%@",documentsDir);
     if(sqlite3_close(database)==SQLITE_OK)
     {
        NSLog(@"DB Connection closed successfully");
        return YES;
     }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"Error Failed to close DB because     %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
       return NO;
    }
 }
```

My Insertion Method is :

```
 - (void) addToDatabase :(NSString*) sqlstmt :(NSArray *)params
 {
sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlstmt UTF8String], -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

else
{
    for (i=1; i<=[params count]; i++)
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, i,[[params objectAtIndex:i-1] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    }
}

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
else

    NSLog(@"%lld",sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));


sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
```

}

While adding to database i am getting database locked error because while one response is open the database and inserting into database parallely another response try to open the database connection,so how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Show the code you're using and when you get the error

Comment: You might want to create another queue for writing to database. Operations for this queue should be created in server-response blocks. And max concurrent operations for this queue should be set to 1.

Comment: what do u mean by server-response blocks and how to start another queue once every response download has been completed?

Comment: can u tell me how to implement inserting the response datas into database parallely without database locked error?